# How do I stop my page from repeating my functions?

Tags: php

On my index page I'm calling a function it looks like this:

```
case 'deposit':
        $balance = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'deposit', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        $accountID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'accountID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        deposit($balance, $accountID);
        break;
```

This is what the function is currently doing:

```
function deposit($balance, $accountID) {
    global $db;
    $dquery = "UPDATE bankaccount SET balance = balance + :balance WHERE accountID = :accountID";
    try{
        $dStatement = $db-> prepare($dquery);
        $dStatement->bindValue(':balance', $balance);
        $dStatement->bindValue(':accountID', $accountID);
        $dStatement->execute();
        $dStatement->closeCursor();

    }catch (Exception $e){
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo "error". $error_message;
    }

}
```

My problem is that every time the index page is refreshed the function runs again adding more to my database. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Also, the switch statement is based off actions connected to buttons on the main view page. If you press "deposit" deposit action then gets a value of 'deposit'.

Comment: Would it be because money flows? Or would it be that this is unanswerable due to the fact that we have no clue whatsover on what `case 'deposit'` fires?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to another page after the SQL queries are finished, using

```
header('Location: https://www.yourdomain.com/nextPage.php');
```

Alternatively, you can use session variables to store the url and the timestamp of the last visit of the page. If you see that the last visit was just 15 minutes ago, you can decide to not run the function again.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is that your `POST` requests should return a redirect to another `GET` resource using the `Location:` header, instead of render another HTML document.